# Exchange one file in a branch of a git repository

Tags: git

I have a file `config.txt` in a given branch of a remote git repository.

Now I have a new version of that file (outside of any git repository, just a generated file) and want to commit it. For that, I need to write a shell script. What would be a good approach for that?

Do I need a local copy of the whole git repository? Or can it be done more directly?

Comment: Can you clarify the bit with a shell script? Am I guessing correctly you would like to automate the update of `config.txt`?

Comment: @mimikrija Yes, I need to automatically update the content of the file from a pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember that what Git really cares about are *commits*, and each commit is a full snapshot of all files.  Moreover, each commit is made from whatever is in Git's *index* at the time you run `git commit`.  A `git checkout` of a given commit fills the index from that commit, while also populating a work-tree with those files (in their ordinary form) so that you can see them.

Thus, if you want to make a new commit in which all files are the same as the previous commit *except* for `config.txt` which should be replaced wholesale, you must:

- fill the index with those files
- replace the `config.txt` file in the index with the new contents
- commit the resulting index

The easy way to do that is to have the repository—or a clone of it—with a work-tree in location *W* (some directory/folder on your machine), in a "clean" state (so that `git status` in *W* will say `nothing to commit, working tree clean`).  Then, in *W*, do:

```
git checkout branchname
```

which fills the index and work-tree of the repository in *W*.  Then you can:

```
cp <path> config.txt
```

(where *`path`* is the new generated confing), then:

```
git add config.txt
git commit -m "replace config.txt with new generated config"
```

If this repository is copied from some other Git repository elsewhere, you can now `git push` the new commit to that other Git repository, and ask that Git repository to update *its* branch name to incorporate the new commit (which of course remembers its predecessor as usual).

Remember that this `git push` may be racing against other users who are also updating that other Git, so it might fail if *they* updated the other Git's branch.  In this case, you should probably mostly start over: update the local clone to pick up their new commit(s), hard-reset the one branch, copy the generated `config.txt`, add, commit, and push.  If that fails, restart yet again, until it succeeds.

(If there is a constraint by which the named branch should *not* have been updated by anyone else in this time period, you can skip the restart-and-retry loop, and simply report any failure for some human to diagnose.)

> Do I need a local copy of the whole git repository?

You need *enough of* the Git repository to be able to check out the target branch (thus populating index and work-tree), replace the one file, `git add`, `git commit`, and `git push`.  How much is "enough"?  Well, all you really need is the one *current* branch tip of that one named branch, so a shallow clone of depth 1 suffices.  Hence if you *don't* have a repository at all, you can start the retry loop with:

```
git clone --depth 1 --single-branch -b <branch-name> <url> [<local-dir>]
```

to obtain this shallow clone in whatever directory.  Should the push fail and you wish to have a retry loop, you can just `git fetch` in this now-existing shallow clone to update `origin/branch-name`, then use `git reset --hard origin/branch-name` to reset for the next add/commit/push attempt.  You should probably then *remove* this repository as shallow single-branch clones are something of a sand-trap / tar-pit / whatever your favorite term might be for other humans who stumble across them and aren't prepared for all the sharp pointy bits that shallow and single-branch repositories present.

> Or can it be done more directly?

Rather than doing all of this on a client, in a clone, and `git push`ing to the server Git, you *could* send the newly generated `config.txt` to the server—to a location outside *its* clone, which is probably `--bare` anyway—by some non-Git method (such as `scp` or `rsync`) and run something directly on the *server*.  This, of course, assumes you have that kind of access to the server.

If you have a bare repository—which is one with no work-tree—you can still make a new commit, because even a bare repository has an index.  You simply need to read the existing branch-tip commit into the index:

```
git read-tree <branch-name>
```

then replace that one file in the index using `git update-index` (with `--stdin` or `--cacheinfo`), but to do so you'll need to use `git hash-object -w` to create the blob object from the desired content.  Then, having updated the index, use `git write-tree` to write a new tree object, then use `git commit-tree` to build a commit from the resulting tree object, and last, use `git update-ref` to update the branch name to point to the new commit.  If the branch might be updated via `git push`, you'll still need a retry loop, or some method of locking the branch against `git push`.  Any locking method is up to you to invent, perhaps using hooks.